# Is it possible to run the rank function on top of a query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, window-functions

I am trying to learn windows function in MY SQL. All I want to know is that if I can do a rank function using a query in the from clause like I have shown below in MYSQL.

```
SELECT s.classroom
     , rank() over ( order by s.cnt desc) row_no
  from (
select classroom,count(*) as cnt
  from list
 group 
    by classroom
)s;
```

Comment: I don't understand the basis of the question.  What's wrong with your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your query is valid SQL - assuming that you are running MySQL 8.0, since earlier versions do not support window functions such as `rank()`.

Note, however, that you don't actually need a subquery for this. You can use the window function directly in the aggregate query:

```
select
    classroom,
    count(*) cnt,
    rank() over(order by count(*) desc) row_no
from list
group by classroom
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i guess the issue was with the version. Appreciate your suggestion as well